# Replacing C loop w/range operator - Segmentation Fault: 11 When used w/? chaining

Tags: swift, swift2

Edit: This is happening because I'm accessing the SomeArrayWrapper instance through a property and/or method with optional chaining. I've updated my example.

I'm having an issue this morning updating a project to Swift 2.2.

This is an example of what I have:

```
//wraps an array
class SomeArrayWrapper<T> {

    var privateArray = [T]()

    // returns count from private array
    var count: Int { get {

        return self.privateArray.count
        }
    }
}

class SomeClass {

    var list: SomeArrayWrapper<Int>?
}

let someInstance = SomeClass()

// Somewhere else I need to use this like this:
let myArrayType = SomeArrayWrapper<Int>()

for var i = 0; i < someInstance.list?.count; i++ {

// Do things.
}

// Replacing the C style loop with:
for i in 0..<someInstance.list?.count {


}
// Reults in a segmentation fault 11 at compile time.
```

I'm going through this change as the C loop results in a warning. I haven't conformed my custom structures to Sequence or Collections (I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it).

Is this a Swift 2.2 bug or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @user3441734 I have discovered it is using the ranger operator through something that uses optional chaining.

Comment: @thefredelement You should post your solution as an _answer_ to your own question, not as a modification of the question itself. This could help someone else. Answering your own question is legal and encouraged on Stack Overflow; in 48 hours you can even accept your own answer (no rep points for doing that, of course)

Comment: @matt I've added it as an answer but I'm not sure it is an answer, should there be an explicit error for trying to use a ranger operator like this? Or should it be allowed?

Comment: binary operator '..<' cannot be applied to operands of type T and T? the compiler should not crash, but report an error ...

Comment: The compiler itself should never crash - whatever you are doing. If it crashes, you should report it as a bug.

Comment: @Sulthan I agree. This is a good bug. - I've added your use of `??` to my answer, by the way; this is not an attempt to steal, though, so if you want to give your own answer, I'll delete mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your solution of force-unwrapping the Optional does "work" (in the sense that it prevents the segfault), wouldn't it be better, as in most cases, to take the time and trouble to unwrap the Optional *safely*? Like this:

```
if let count = someInstance.list?.count {
    for i in 0..<count {
        // ...
    }
}
```

As Sulthan has pointed out, you can express that even more neatly by using a default value that causes the loop not to happen:

```
for i in 0..<(someInstance.list?.count ?? 0) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I agree, in my case I guard against the property not being nil first then force unwrap it for the loop.

Comment: he experienced a segmentation fault 11 at compile time ... i am not able to repeat his trouble

Comment: I can reproduce the segfault @user3441734

Comment: that is interesting ... my is Version 7.3 (7D175), downloaded an hour before

Comment: @thefredelement And the `??` operator makes this even neater

Comment: "I agree, in my case I guard against the property not being nil first then force unwrap it" No, @thefredelement, if you have guarded correctly you do not _need_ to force unwrap. That is the point of my answer.

Comment: Adding @Sulthan 's rec. in ( ) makes it the best answer, thank you.